# Bootstrap 4 hex colors for rails app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Does anyone know where to find a list of bootstrap 4 colors in hex?  i looked at the docs, maybe i missed it?

My issue is that I'm trying to match some colors on my site to the bootstrap 4 "bg-primary", "btn-primary", etc... colors.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The easiest way to get the *default* values used in Bootstrap is to check the scss variables in the source. Since the package is available publicly from Github you can do this even without installing it. The variables are set in the [bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss)
 file.

The *default* colors are as follows:

```
// Colors
$blue:    #007bff !default; // primary
$indigo:  #6610f2 !default;
$purple:  #6f42c1 !default;
$pink:    #e83e8c !default;
$red:     #dc3545 !default; // danger
$orange:  #fd7e14 !default;
$yellow:  #ffc107 !default; // warning
$green:   #28a745 !default; // success
$teal:    #20c997 !default;
$cyan:    #17a2b8 !default; // info

// Grays
$white:    #fff !default;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa !default; // light
$gray-200: #e9ecef !default;
$gray-300: #dee2e6 !default;
$gray-400: #ced4da !default;
$gray-500: #adb5bd !default;
$gray-600: #868e96 !default; // secondary
$gray-700: #495057 !default;
$gray-800: #343a40 !default; // dark
$gray-900: #212529 !default;
$black:    #000 !default;
```

Comment: Awesome!  thank you.